# count using inner join from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `Document_type_de` and the other is `document` . `Document` table has all the documents stored but which type of document it is, is defined in `document_type_de`, so i need help with the query which will help me find the count of the documents of each type in the document table.

columns under document_type_de table

```
ID, display name
```

columns under document table

```
documenttypede
```

Comment: use GROUP BY. If you are not familiar google it.

Comment: check [**JOIN**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) Then `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
SELECT Type.[Display Name], 
       COUNT(*) AS [Number of Documents]
FROM Document_type_de Type
JOIN Document D
    ON Type.ID = D.documenttypede
GROUP BY Type.[Display Name]
ORDER BY Type.[Display Name]
```

Comment: thanks everyone. I used this
SELECT 
DT.DISPLAYNAME, COUNT(DO.DOCUMENTTYPEDE) AS NUMBER
FROM DOCUMENT_TYPE_DE AS DT WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN DOCUMENT AS DO WITH (NOLOCK)
ON DT.ID=DO.DOCUMENTTYPEDE

GROUP BY DT.DISPLAYNAME

Answer (score 0):

That query will give you the count of all the documents grouped by documents_type_id. Dunno about you tables primarys and foreign keys names, just replace it.

```
SELECT count(documents_id) 
FROM document d
INNER JOIN Document_type_de dtd dtd.document_id = d.document_id
GROUP BY d.documents_type_id
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT document_type_de.id, document_type_de.name, COUNT(document.documenttypede) 
FROM document_type_de 
INNER JOIN document ON document_type_de.id = document.documenttypede 
GROUP BY document_type_de.id;
```

I think this should do it, if I got all names right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dt.Display_Name, Count(*)
From Document d
Left Join document_type_de dt on dt.Id = d.Id
Group by dt.Display_Name
```

Comment: Why are you using a left join?

Comment: What if there is a document type stored in the documents table that does not exist in the document type table.   Inner Join would remove that record from the result set.   With a left join, I will also be able to see if that situation exists because document_type description would be NULL.

Comment: While that's correct, that issue is best resolved through the use of foreign keys (relational database), rather than trying to deal with it in every query that you write.  Furthermore, because the name of the column in the Document table matches the name of the document type table ("documenttypede"), I think it's safe to assume that the aforementioned integrity exists.